# XML serialization with no value

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

How to serialize in c#

```
<Tag>
 <Export />
 <Delete />
</Tag>
```

The problem is node has no value. Node present in xml means it is true(bool).

Comment: What serialization framework are you using? With e.g. XDocument this is trivial. With XmlSerializer it's a little harder.

Comment: using System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
public class Export { }
public class Delete { }

public class Tag
{
    public Export Export { get; set; }      
    public Delete Delete { get; set; }  
}
```

and then:

```
var tag = new Tag()
{
    Export = new Export(),
    Delete = new Delete(),
};
serializer.Serialize(writer, tag);
```

Alternatively, we can use `IXmlSerializable`:

```
public class Tag : IXmlSerializable
{
    public bool HasExport { get; set; }
    public bool HasDelete { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema() => null;

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        if (HasExport)
            writer.WriteElementString("Export", null);
        if (HasDelete)
            writer.WriteElementString("Delete", null);
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        // TODO...
    }
}
```

and then:

```
var tag = new Tag()
{
    HasExport = true,
    HasDelete = true,
};
serializer.Serialize(writer, tag);
```